# when is kotlin reflect lib necessary?

Tags: android, kotlin, reflection, kotlin-reflect

In the docs ( https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html ) it is not mentioned what features of the reflection api are included in the reflection library. 
I can do basic reflection (listing members,parameters,etc) without explicitly referencing this library. 
When do i have to include it on android ?

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, the main types (such as [`KClass`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-class/)) are in the standard library's `kotlin.reflect` package. But most of their extension properties and functions are in [`kotlin.reflect.full`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect.full/index.html); that's provided by `kotlin-reflect`. So is [`kotlin.reflect.jvm`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect.jvm/index.html).